# Is it possible to create something like shapecollage.com, using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I was thinking... Is it possible to create an application that can add effects similar to what shape collage does? I know, it was made using java. Could something like that be built using as3?

My idea is that it uses alpha to know, where to start adding the shapes. In php its possible to read every pixel of an image, to check its color, so we can know if it is alpha or not, so i think there is something similar in as3. The images could be uploaded thru filerefence.

Do you have any other idea, about how does it works to help me in this project?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here's some of the source which includes basic path tracing and matching to plot picture placement along the outline of text. In the code it takes a text field that says LOVE and reads it's alpha to plot coordinates and places objects representing images to form the letters.

http://code.google.com/p/ascensionsystems/downloads/list

It's in the downloads section you'll see it there. Code is probably a little crude because it was an experiment but it works quite well and should make for a good head start.

**Original Answer**

LOL wow! I was actually hired by this guy to port this to AS3. Yes it is possible I can say that much. I'll dig around see if I can find what source code I do have. The guy is very impatient, he actually fired me after just a couple days because I wasn't done. Oh how happy I am that I left the freelance world behind. Anyway simple answer it is possible I'll update with a link if/when I find the source.

Comment: And yes, you're on the right track you can simply use bitmapData.getPixel32() and provide x/y coordinates to retrieve the pixel data and check the colour.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's amazing what we can find here at stackoverflow... That's all that I need to develop my project.

Comment: lol yeah I was pretty surprised to find this myself. All the best.

Comment: hello. I sent you an e-mail thru your website. Check it please.